# How to send confirmation email after submitting data using filemaker pro

Tags: filemaker

I am very new to filemaker pro. Is there a way where I can get a conformation email after the user submits an entry using filemaker pro?

So for example, when the user clicks "Submit", it will automatically send me a confirmation email that says someone has submitted a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the [Send Mail] script step. You can specify an SMTP server to use (which allows you to specify an account to use), or else use the locally connected user's email client (in which case the email will show as coming from the user)

Answer (score 0):

Years ago we used the send mail step to send an alert to ourselves as outlined above. Over the years we moved away from this to a method we found more effective.

If your volume is consistent consider using FileMaker to report to you rather than emailing yourself.  There is less to go wrong and you probably have to be in FileMaker to use the data.

Create a flag field set to "open" in the table that you check off when you've done what ever you will do with the information. Then create a calc field that shows how many open items you have.

For example we have an online store that uses FileMaker as a backend.  The user screens have a  field that appears as a little red ball with a number of open orders in it if there are unprocessed orders.  If all the orders are processes the ball is green.